# Is it possible to calculate MFCC vectors using the AudioKit API for Swift?

Tags: swift, audio-processing, mfcc, audiokit

Looking at the AudioKit documentation, the only analysis nodes are for frequency and amplitude, and there is an FFT tap for FFT calculation on any node. Is there a way calculate MFCC vectors, and/or are the developer looking to add this functionality in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an AKFFTTap that can tap any node. There are no plans to calculate MFCC vectors, but AudioKit is open source, so if anyone wants to add it, we'll be grateful.